# How to place a currency symbol prefix or postfix with a string?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslocale, currency-formatting

I'm wondering if there is any official way to put a currency symbol to the left or to the right from the money amount, depending of the region and the currency itself?
For example, if it's a $ sign, it should be to the left of the amount, as $20. If it's, for instance, € sign, then it should go as 20€.
I've found a simple way, I just check with If statement if the currency symbol is $ and append it to the left or to the right to my NSString. But this looks a bit lame like a crutch method.
I was unable to find some more convenient way. Is there any?
Thank you.

Comment: [NSNumberFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNumberFormatter/setCurrencyCode:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apples official way ......

You need to use NSNumbers and NSNumberFormatter to convert the value to a currency and return a string representing it. This can be used in our labels e.t.c. someDouble refers to the number you wish to convert to a currency format.

```
NSNumber *currencyValue = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:someDouble];
NSNumberFormatter *formater = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formater setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
NSString *currencyString = [formater stringFromNumber:currencyValue];
```

NOTE: you may need to play around with the `setLocale` to get it to display the correct currency for a given region.